Is the set of functions with positive derivative a.e. sequentially compact over the topology of pointwise convergence?
Consider the following set $H = \{ f :[0,1]\to[0,1]  | \frac{df}{dx} \geq 0 \text{ a.e.} \}$, I was wondering if this set could be a sequentially compact set over the pointwise convergence topology, that means, if we have a sequence $f_n \in H$ we can find a convergent subsequence $f_{n_i} \to f \in H$.
First I tried to use the Helly selection theorem to prove it, but it doesn't work here because $H \neq \{ f: [0,1]\to [0,1]|\text{ monotone non-decresing} \}$.

When you write $\frac{df}{dx}$, are you referring to the pointwise derivative or to some weak notion of derivative?

@Pelota, I am using the standard notion of derivative, $\frac{df}{dx}(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}$, and I am assuming that the limit exists a.e..

@Jochen, the image of $f_n(x) = nx$ isn't in $[0,1]$, so this sequence is not in $H$. I don't understand how to use this sequence to produce a counter-example.

Sorry for my careless comment which I deleted. Good question!

It is not sequentially compact. Consider the following sequence of elements of $H$:
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, \; \frac{i}{2^n} \leq x < \frac{i+1}{2^n} \; \text{where} \; 0 \leq i < 2^n \; \text{and} \; i \; \text{is even}\\
1 &, \; \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Indeed, $f_n \in H$ since $\frac{df_n}{dx}$ exists and is $0$ a.e. However, $f_n$ admits no pointwise convergent subsequence. Indeed, it is not hard to show that the events $\{x: f_n(x) = 0\}$ are independent between different $n$ and each one has measure $\frac{1}{2}$. Similarly for events $\{x: f_n(x) = 1\}$. If $f_{n_k}$ is a pointwise convergent subsequence, then for any $x$, $f_{n_k}(x)$ must be $0$ for all but finitely many $k$ or must be $1$ for all but finitely many $k$. Thus,
$$[0, 1] = (\bigcup_{K > 0} \{x: f_{n_k}(x) = 0 \; \text{for all} \; k \geq K\}) \cup (\bigcup_{K > 0} \{x: f_{n_k}(x) = 1 \; \text{for all} \; k \geq K\})$$
The set on the RHS is a countable union of null sets, so it has measure $0$ itself, a contradiction.

A different way of understanding $f_n$ that might make this clearer: it’s simply the function that picks out the $n$-th digit in the binary representation.
